# Does HSQLDB support default values for enums in MySQL compat mode?

Tags: mysql, hsqldb

I'm using an in-memory HSQLDB instance (version 2.5.1) for Java unit tests. The instance has MySQL compatibility mode enabled. The following create statement works:

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
  is_subscribed enum('y','n') NOT NULL
)
```

However, if I try adding in a default value like this:

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
  is_subscribed enum('y','n') DEFAULT 'n' NOT NULL
)
```

I get the following error message:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: DEFAULT : line: 3 in statement [CREATE TABLE people
```

Is there a way to specify a default value for an enum type?

Comment: Did you try `NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n'`? That is, just reverse the order of the column options. The [syntax doc](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html#create_table-section) shows that DEFAULT goes before NOT NULL, but it should be a quick test to confirm that.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, I did try but it didn't work. As you said, the docs require that DEFAULT be placed first, and HSQLDB seems to throw an exception if the order is reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB versions up to 2.5.1 do not support the DEFAULT clause directly for MySQL ENUM declarations. This may be supported in later versions.

You can add the DEFAULT after the table is created. Use:

```
ALTER TABLE people ALTER COLUMN is_subscribed SET DEFAULT 'n'
```

Update: This is now supported in the latest code. You can check out the code and build the jar. The update will appear in the next release.